# Why my Angular App is not connecting with Firestore Emulator?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, gcloud, firebase-tools

I have an Angular App set with AngularFire

```
Angular CLI: 15.2.9
Node: 18.16.1
Package Manager: yarn 1.22.19
OS: linux x64

Angular: 15.2.9
... animations, cdk, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core
... forms, material, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router, service-worker

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1502.9
@angular-devkit/build-angular   15.2.9
@angular-devkit/core            15.2.9
@angular-devkit/schematics      15.2.9
@angular/fire                   7.6.1
@schematics/angular             15.2.9
rxjs                            7.8.1
typescript                      4.9.5
```

I've set the firestore emulator in app module like this:

```js
@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [
   provideFirestore(() => {
      let firestore: Firestore;
      if (environment.useEmulators) {
        firestore = initializeFirestore(getApp(), {
          ssl: false
        });
        connectFirestoreEmulator(firestore, 'localhost', 8080);
      } else {
        firestore = getFirestore();
      }
      return firestore;
    }),
  ]
  ...
})
```

And with this as environment file (changing sensitive data):

```
export const environment = {
  appName: 'Awesome App Name',
  useEmulators: true,
  firebase: {
    projectId: 'demo-project',
    appId: 'valid-app-id',
    storageBucket: 'valid-storage-bucket',
    apiKey: 'valid-api-key',
    authDomain: 'demo-project',
    messagingSenderId: 'valid-messaging-sender-id',
  },
};
```

And then I have a service which have this writing method:

```js
  ...
  private db = getFirestore();

  constructor() {}

  saveTimeWindow(timeWindow: string, userId: string) {
    const docRef = doc(
      this.db,
      AvailabilityService.TimeWindowCollectionName,
      userId
    );
    return setDoc(docRef, { timeWindow, userId });
  }

  getTimeWindow(userId: string): Observable<TimeWindow> {
    const docRef = doc(
      this.db,
      AvailabilityService.TimeWindowCollectionName,
      userId
    );
    return docData(docRef) as Observable<TimeWindow>;
  }
  ...
```

The problem is that as soon I initialize the component I'm subscribing to what getTimeWindow returns, and then I try to save data with saveTimeWindow, I'm getting this error message:

> [2023-09-12T16:21:54.262Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (9.23.0): Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Connection failed 1 times. Most recent error: FirebaseError: [code=permission-denied]: Cloud Firestore API has not been used in project demo-project before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/firestore.googleapis.com/overview?project=demo-project then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.
> This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.

I know the app can reach the emulators, because I'm using the Authentication Emulator and works fine.

And I shouldn't "enable" my demo-project if it's suppoused to work everything in my computer, should it?

What am I missing?

I'm starting the emulators like this:

`"start": "firebase emulators:exec --project demo-project --ui 'ng serve'",`

I see the Emulators Panel with all the emulators running. Also, I don't see any request in the "requests" tab in Firestore.

I'm running out of ideas, please help!

I've followed the steps provided by [Joshua Morony (great channel, btw)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B0-Rl5Vy4Fs)

I've checked the [documentation here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_firestore?hl=en&authuser=0#web-modular-api)

ChatGPT asked me to stop asking